# React Router V6 Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a PrivateRoute logic with the newly released Router but it seems it doesn't work as expected..

```js
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import LogInPage from "./pages/LogIn";
import DashboardPage from "./pages/Dashboard";

function PrivateRoute({ path, element }) {
  const auth = true;

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      element={auth === true ? element : <Navigate replace to="/login" />}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/dashboard" />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LogInPage />} />
      <PrivateRoute
        path="/dashboard"
        element={<DashboardPage />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I missing? Isn't the PrivateRoute component still a `Route` component if it is returning a `Route` ?

Comment: See the official react-router v6 [auth example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/examples/auth.md) for private routing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the way you mentioned and it works perfectly.. Unfortunately I am more interested the way I specified above if it works... To me that seems more convenient rather than wrapping each element of a Route in a RequireAuth component..

Comment: Please read this https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5

Comment: Another option is to separate public and private routes using a common path. For example anything at `/*` is public and anything at `/app/*` is private. These `Route`s will contain parent `element`s that contains a `Routes` component that wraps their respective `Route` components. At the top-level of the private parent component, you'll check for authentication. If it passes, it falls into the private `Routes` switch; otherwise, you can redirect/show an overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You cannot compose](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f#route-composition-in-react-router-v6) `Route`s in React Router v6. Instead, create the Route at the same level as the others, and use your PrivateRoute component inside the `element` prop. Example ([source](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f#route-composition-in-react-router-v6)):

```js
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/public" element={<PublicPage />} />
      <Route
        path="/protected"
        element={
          // Good! Do your composition here instead of wrapping <Route>.
          // This is really just inverting the wrapping, but it's a lot
          // more clear which components expect which props.
          <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  let isAuthenticated = getAuth();
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

### Routing in React V6

1. Used for navigation in case of multiple pages in a website. We need not to re-render the whole website to navigate to a different page
   everytime , making a fetch request to a server.
2. Whole javascript is fecthed at once and then managed by react-router-dom a third party lib for navigation.

```js
   //npm install react-router-dom
   
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
       <Route path='' element='' exact> //exact is used to load only the specified matched path
       <Route path='' element=''>
        .
        . 
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

3. Redirecting :- To redirect a path to a prexisting Path.

   ```js
       import { Routes,Routes,Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
       <Routes>
          <Route path='/learn' element={<Learn/>}/>
          <Route path='/learn-apps' element={<Navigate replace to="/learn"/>}/>
       </Routes>
   ```
4. Extracting Parameters from a Route Path :-

   ```js
           //define a path like this
           <Route path=":courseid" element={<CourseId/>}/>

           //In the component use react router hook 
           function CourseId(){
             let {courseid} = useParams();
             return (
               <div>
                 <h1>Your Course Id is : {courseid}</h1>
               </div>
             );
           }
   ```
5. Carrying Information from route to another route.

   - for this functionality we have to use two hooks i.e. useNavigate,useLocation
   - Lets say we carrying information from a courseId component to a Dashboard ,henceforth the route is changed, so to pass away some info :-
   - Here we are passing a object containing price whenever a user click a button on the courseId component to new Route i.e. dashboard
   - ```js
        function CourseId(){
          //useNavigate is imported from react-router-dom
          let navigate = useNavigate();
          let {courseid} = useParams();
          return (
              <div>
                <h1>Your Course Id is : {courseid} </h1>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    navigate("/dashboard",{ state: {
                      price : "399"
                    } });
                  }}
                >Pass information</button>
              </div>
            );
          }

          function Dashboard(){
              const location = useLocation();
              return(
                <div>
                  <h1>Info that I got here is {location.state.price} </h1>
                </div>
              );
            }
     ```

     - Another simple way of doing is it with using Links
     - ```js
          //Route intial
          <Link to="/dashboard" state={"DJANGO"}>Dashboard</Link>

          //Route final
          const location = useLocation();
          <h1>Info that I got here is {location.state} </h1>
       ```

[Sources : Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cSVuySEB0A)